# How to run programs from a different directory in unix

Tags: unix

I know this is a very simple question, and that many similar (but more complicated!) questions have been asked- So i wanted to ask this in a very plane manner. Sorry if this voids the rules of conduct on this website! I'm very new to using unix.

I have a program that converts a ".evt" file to an .rq1, which is used for data analysis. The command to do so is simple, for example: Convert data.evt (this outputs data.rq1).

This program, let's say, is located in directory /A and I have a data file that I want to convert in directory /B. How would I go about executing this program without moving the convert program to directory B?

Comment: any problem with changing to directory `/B` and executing `/A/program` ?

Answer (score 4):

It is very simple:

```
./A/Convert B/some_file
```

It means go to the directory A and run the program with parameter that you will give.

Comment: Wow thanks so much for the quick response that really is quite simple- everything else I've tried seemed to be much more complicated (and more "robust") than what I needed.

Comment: Note that the "dot" means current directory, so the above won't work unless `A` is in whatever directory you are in.

Answer (score 3):

In UNIX File System, all your inbuilt commands are binaries (programs) written to perform certain tasks. `ls` command does the listing of directories, `mv` command moves or renames files etc.

All these binaries are stored in your `/usr/bin` directory. And the path to that directory is stored in your PATH environment variable.

If you have many scripts that do certain tasks, I would recommend them to move in one folder. say for example, `/yourname/scripts` and then set this path in your PATH variable.

PATH variable can be set in your .bashrc or .bash_profile file which gets loaded up whenever you fire a terminal session. You can view your PATH variable settings by doing an `echo` on it.

`[jaypal~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.12/bin:/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems:/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/wkpdf-0.5.3-universal-darwin/bin:/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/wkpdf-0.5.3-universal-darwin/lib`

In your .profile file, simply add `:/yourname/scripts` folder and do `. .profile` on your shell prompt. This will force your current session to load your profile file without having to quit and log in again.

Once the .profile file has been loaded, you can run your script from anywhere by simply typing `scriptname` options or other arguments as needed.

This [tutorial](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html#sect_02_01) will be helpful to you.

Comment: no one should **ever** add a directory to PATH just to be able to run a single program from it, `ln -s` is a way better solution

Comment: What could be the potential issue? It's not just for running one program. All user created scripts can be placed in one such folder and can be called in from any location.

Comment: If it's not just for running a single program then you place it in **~/bin** -- it is automatically added to the PATH by bash. This is a _standard_ approach unlike your _/yourname/scripts_

Comment: Yea, you can do that too. I feel more comfortable having a separate folder containing scripts I write, keeping them separate from the binaries that comes with my distribution. I still don't see a potential pitfall in adding a folder to my PATH variable.

Comment: nothing comes with your distribution in **~/bin**, it is solely for **your** own scripts

Comment: ~/bin folder does not exist. You have to create it. No difference if you create ~/bin or any folder and put your scripts in it.  It boils down to your preference.

Comment: I don't see how it boils down to preference...
1) **~/bin** is a Unix standard name to store your own scripts
2) **~/bin** is automatically added to the PATH variable if bash finds it.... unless your preference is spending more effort and not following Unix naming conventions

Comment: /bin should be used to store binaries for emergency repairs, booting etc.  Why would you clutter this with your scripts.?

Comment: do you feel the difference between `/bin` and `~/bin` ?

Answer (score 1):

> One convention used by most experienced unix users (not supplied by the system) is to create a local bin directory--inside the user's home directory--as a repository for user-created scripts and programs. (taken from [here](http://scope.msu.montana.edu/bash/?page=user-accounts/home-bin-directory))

Place you program in `~/bin` directory (which is a short for `/home/yourname/bin`) and you will be able to run your program from any location, because when `~/bin` exists bash adds it to the `PATH` by default (at least on Ubuntu). You will need to create this directory if it doesn't exist.

If you feel like becoming a more advanced linux user - use `ln -s` to link your program from its location to `~/bin`

Answer (score 0):

```
/path/to/A/Convert /path/to/B/data.evt
```

...and your output file should end up in your current directory (assuming you have write access).

Additionally, what flavor of Unix are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Run it just like so:

```
/A/Convert /B/data.evt
```

Remember not to lead /A with a `.` as `,` means current directory. Unless of course the path you're providing is relative to the current directory.